# How do I measure the bandwidth of SSH tunnel VPN?

Tags: vpn, bandwidth-measuring, dropbear

I use dropbear for SSH tunneling, and I use this method as a VPN.
Is there a way to find how much bandwidth that I have used per SSH account?